# Существуют ли средства C++, позволяющие выключить графическую оболочку и перевести Linux в режим командной строки?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, lubuntu

У меня возникла идея фикс, написать программу "Лариса Андреевна, спокойной ночи!", чтобы она проверяла имя пользователя, проверяла время и сразу после полуночи превращала компьютер в бесполезный предмет, наподобие как в сказке про Золушку, вплоть до 8 утра. Реализовать базовый функционал на Си++ оказалось довольно просто, но вот сейчас думаю сделать, чтобы сначала вырубалась графическая оболочка и компьютер переходил в режим командной строки, чтобы по экрану пробежались напутствия и пожелание приятных снов. Система у нас Linux Lubuntu 20.04. Пожалуйста, подскажите, где копать информацию на эту тему.

Comment: остановите gdm или что у Вас там отвечает за это и все будет. Либо попробуйте перейти на правильный уровень выполнения - "init 3"

Comment: писать в консоль через /dev/tty1